# How to build SAPUI5 application that should only have "component-preload.js"?

Tags: build, gulp, sapui5, preload, ui5-tooling

I need to build the SAPUI5/OpenUI5 test application with only the "component-preload.js" file included. Within the 'dist' folder, there shouldn't be any "TS/JS/DBG" files, as illustrated below. Is there a specific command or task available to accomplish this?
[Sample Application with dist generated png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivc89.png)

When utilizing the "Exclude-task=createDebugFiles", debug files are successfully eliminated, but TypeScript (TS) and JavaScript (JS) files still appear in the dist directory.
[Using excludeTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpRQd.png)

Comment: Please follow https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3998#issuecomment-1991332692 and consider adding an answer for future readers how the issue could be resolved accordingly